# Pandas create unique rows and split columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
name    channel    value
a1      branch     150
a2      online     200
a1      branch     120
a1      online     100
a3      branch     120
a3      branch     200
```

or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", "a3", "a3"], 
                   "channel": ["branch", "online", "branch", "online", "branch", "branch"], 
                   "value":[150, 200, 120, 100, 120, 200]})
```

I want to create new dataframe with only 1 unique name per row and then each unique channel name on separate columns with value equals to total of that channel. I.e.:

```
name    channel_branch    channel_online     branch_value     online_value
a1      yes               yes                270              100
a2      no                yes                0                200
a3      yes               no                 320              0
```

I was thinking of doing merge by creating unique dataframe from df using the following:

```
df_unique = pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates(df, subset="name")
```

and then do left merge using the following:

```
merged = pd.merge(df_unique, df, on="name", how="left")
```

But that doesn't work as per what i'm trying to achieve. I'm new to Python and Pandas. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df = df.pivot_table('value', 'name', 'channel', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0).add_suffix('_value').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
>>> df.join(df.select_dtypes(include=np.int64).gt(0).replace({1: 'Yes', 0: 'No'}).add_prefix('channel_'))
  name  branch_value  online_value channel_branch_value channel_online_value
0   a1           270           100                  Yes                  Yes
1   a2             0           200                   No                  Yes
2   a3           320             0                  Yes                   No
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works (got an error at first as i didn't import numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
output = df.groupby(["name", "channel"], as_index=False).sum().pivot("name", "channel", "value").fillna(0)
output = (output>0).replace({True: 'yes', False: 'no'}).add_prefix("channel_").join(output.add_suffix("_value")).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

>>> output
  name channel_branch channel_online  branch_value  online_value
0   a1            Yes            Yes         270.0         100.0
1   a2             No            Yes           0.0         200.0
2   a3            Yes             No         320.0           0.0
```

Comment: Well it would help resetting the index and the column index name